# Load XML get specific ID's contents jQuery or Javascript

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, load

I am trying to parse a XML feed and then grab just one specific ID and the contents there-in out of it. I need to do this with JS only...

I have tried various ways with no luck. The closest I get is using:

```
var html = $("#dangericon").html();
$("#test").append( html );
```

However, this will not work for me when I try to load the xml first. It must be in the page... see: http://jsfiddle.net/BZDBF/5/

I have tried:
.ajax,.load, and also .parseXML(), however, that is not working due to improperly formatted XML...

My xml link is: http://www.sierraavalanchecenter.org/bottomline-rss.php
I would like to just get the #dangericon contents, ie the image.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What do you want to show with the fiddle? Where is the XML?

Comment: You generally cannot load XML via Javascript (e.g. via $.ajax()) unless the feed is on your domain. You can load and parse it on your server, though. Don't you have access to server-side coding?

Comment: "...that is not working due to improperly formatted XML" - Isn't the solution to that, to make sure that the XML is properly formatted? Or are you not in control of the XML? If you aren't in control, that probably means that the XML is from another domain? In that case it will probably not be possible with JavaScript, due to security limitations.

Comment: no access.. this is just a feed I want to grab data from. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//parse the XML string (wherever it comes from), then find all the `item` tags and select their child `description` tags, now we have all the `description` tags in your XML document
var $xml_parsed = $($.parseXML(xml_string)).find('item').children('description');

//now iterate through the `description` tags and find the `#dangericon` element within each
for (var i = 0, len = $xml_parsed.length; i < len; i++) {

    //to find an element we must create a jQuery object from the text of this `description` tag and then we can use `.find()` to search for the desired element
    var tmp = $($xml_parsed.eq(i).text()).find('#dangericon');

    //you can do what you want with the element now, it is saved in the `tmp` variable
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pdT8S/

I'm assuming that this is being done on the same domain, if that is the case then you don't need to mess with `jsonp` but if you are making the call to your XML document across domains then you will need to look into `jsonp` requests (which are easily made with jQuery as long as the remote server is setup properly).

P.S. I'm local to Truckee and am willing to help with any ski-centric website you are working on.

Comment: Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle that works, but the process for finding the correct element is not quite the same as with an XML document: http://jsfiddle.net/BZDBF/6/

Comment: Hi Jasper. Thanks man for the help. Yes, this would need to use jsonp. I was thinking I could somehow save the SAC feed to a db or string of some sort, then parse it without a problem. 

What I would really like to do is just manipulate what is there to display differently, just like you did there... however, from the remote server.

Comment: @buildakicker You can create a proxy script in a server-side language that grabs the RSS feed (no cross-domain problems will occur server-side) and your JavaScript can reference this server-side script. It would be a good idea to cache the response from the server-side script in a database and update it occasionally. That way you won't be creating unnecessary HTTP requests which increase the latency of the operation.

Comment: I just came back here to ask that... I usually use php and have no issues, but I am trying this via js only. I'll PM you, maybe this would be of interest to you.

Comment: @buildakicker I'm not sure if you can PM users on StackOverflow, but if you go to the Contact page on my website you can easily send me an email: http://www.apexeleven.com/contact.html